# IE Mobile: Can't connect due to error 0x80072f7c

Tags: windows-mobile, ie-mobile

We launched a website for mobile browsers, [m.cozi.com](http://m.cozi.com/), at the end of last year. We chose to provide a lowest-common denominator experience with static HTML and CSS, no JavaScript. It works well for most people, but some of our customers report connectivity problems. I really have no idea how to get any traction on them.

Those who have problems are all running IE Mobile on Windows Mobile. WM6 for sure, possibly WM5 too. Many WM6/IE users have no problem. Naturally, I've never seen any of the phones that do have problems.

Those who do have problems see this when they go to our site:

```
"Alert. The page you are looking for cannot be found
due to unknown error 0x80072f7c."
```

0x80072f7c = `ERROR_WINHTTP_REDIRECT_FAILED`, but I'm reliably informed that winhttp is not present in Windows Mobile.

I've asked our Customer Service team to check that these users can indeed connect to other websites, HTTP and HTTPS, from their mobile browsers.

I thought it might be something to do with the carrier's HTTP proxies. We've had reports of problems from AT&T users and from Rogers users in Canada, but those are major carriers and there are plenty of users who are not having problems with those carriers.

One user reported that on the same phone where IE Mobile is failing, Opera Mobile is working fine.

I asked a contact on the Windows Mobile team about this, but he was unable to find anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes receive that error on my Windows Mobile 5 device when it's docked.  When docked it's supposed to route the internet access through the host computer, but it doesn't always work.  Normally undocking it and plugging it back in fixes it.